# Using asp.net localization for view models error messages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, multilingual, asp.net-core-localization

I'm trying to create multilanguage web app in asp.net razor pages. I have 2 .resx files :
App.Endpoints.RazorPages.UI\Resources\Areas\Account\Pages\SignUp.fa.resx & SignUp.en.resx

and my Singup page is in :
App.Endpoints.RazorPages.UI\Areas\Account\Pages\SignUp.cshtml.cs

and my view model is in
App.Endpoints.RazorPages.UI\ViewModels

```
 public class SignUpVM
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "username_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
     [StringLength(32)]
     public string UserName { get; set; }

...
```

my problem is I have an error on Resources : `typeof(Resources)` because of 'Resources' is inaccessible due to its protection level. and this class is from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting and it's embedded and I can't change it (I must use this class ?)
also my .resx files access level is public.

what should I do to solve this error or is there any other way to use localization for error messages?

Comment: I think you need your `Resources` class to have the same name as the .resx files

Comment: try setting in the properties of your `.resx` files, set the `Access Modifier` to `Public`. make sure you have  using App.Endpoints.RazorPages.UI.Resources.Areas.Account.Pages; in the ViewModel file. make sure that your resource files are in the correct namespace. The `Resource` class that is generated from your `.resx` files should be in a namespace that is accessible from your `ViewModel`.

Comment: it depends on localization settings in your startup file! [this](https://ziyad.info/en/articles/16-Localizing_DataAnnotations) or [this](https://ziyad.info/en/articles/1040-XLocalizer_for_Asp_Net_Core) could help.